# SKU random alphanumeric values generator

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _ 
Cancel As Boolean) 
Dim ltr, rNum, AlphaLtrs 
AlphaLtrs = "ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
selLtr = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 26, 0) 
ltr = Mid(AlphaLtrs, selLtr, 1) 
rNum = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 999999, 0) 
ActiveCell.Value = ltr & rNum 
Target.Offset(0, 1).Select 
End Sub
```

what I need is, to change the doubleclick function into Enter

and also if possible can I add the value of Column A in to the generated code beginning like Jeans-A545145

Comment: Do you just want this to happen when you select a cell in Column B or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds a value to any cell that selected in column B, as long as only one cell is selected. Paste it into the code module for that sheet:

EDIT: Not sure if this is what you want, but now only does it if Target cell is empty:

EDIT 2: Woops, found a bug in the IF. If you select more than one cell, it errors on the `IF Target.Value = ""` part. I separated that into a second IF:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ltr, rNum, AlphaLtrs, selLtr

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(2)) Is Nothing And _
   Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then

        AlphaLtrs = "ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        selLtr = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 26, 0)
        ltr = Mid(AlphaLtrs, selLtr, 1)
        rNum = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 999999, 0)
        Target.Value = Me.Range("A" & Target.Row) & "-" & ltr & rNum
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thats pretty nice, but I am generating SKU , and when I again click it to select the value, it is generating the new number, i think it creates a problem. can we change the click to enter ?

Comment: There is no "Enter" event - only BeforeDoubleClick and BeforeRightClick. How about if it only changed it if there's nothing in it?

Comment: your provided code is superb , just to make sure about copying it and once created randomm number, number will be freezed

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the random number never changes (unless) you clear the cell and then enter it again.

Comment: that will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ltr, rNum, AlphaLtrs
    AlphaLtrs = "ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    selLtr = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 26, 0)
    ltr = Mid(AlphaLtrs, selLtr, 1)
    rNum = Application.RoundUp(Rnd() * 999999, 0)
    ActiveCell.Value = ltr & rNum
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```